# Typescript: how to properly type omitProps helper via generics

Tags: arrays, typescript, reduce

When implementing `omitProps` which should omit provided props from object and return new one, there are errors when resolving types within reduce.

Following works ( immutable approach )

```
export const omitProps = <
  O extends Record<string,any>, 
  K extends keyof O, 
  R extends Omit<O, K> = Omit<O, K>
>(
  obj: O,
  keys: Array<K> | Set<K>,
): R => {
  const keysSet = keys instanceof Array ? new Set(keys) : keys;
  const originalKeys = Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof O>;

  return originalKeys.reduce(
    (acc, keyName) => {      
      return keysSet.has(keyName as K)
         ? acc
         : {
             ...acc,
             [keyName]: obj[keyName],
           };
    {} as R,

  );
};
```

While that works, using spread when creating new object within reduce is very slow operation.

If we wanna implement much faster solution via reference assignemnt TS will complain:

```
export const omitProps = <
  O extends Record<string,any>, 
  K extends keyof O, 
  R extends Omit<O, K> = Omit<O, K>
>(
  obj: O,
  keys: Array<K> | Set<K>,
): R => {
  const keysSet = keys instanceof Array ? new Set(keys) : keys;
  const originalKeys = Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof O>;

  return originalKeys.reduce(
    (acc, keyName) => {      
      if(!keysSet.has(keyName as K)){
        //  ERROR -> Type 'keyof O' cannot be used to index type 'R'.ts(2536)
        acc[keyName] = obj[keyName]
      }

      return acc
    },
    {} as R,
  );
};
```

Only way how to make TS happy is following casting ( basically we're lying to the compiler )

```
export const omitProps = <
  O extends Record<string,any>, 
  K extends keyof O, 
  R extends Omit<O, K> = Omit<O, K>
>(
  obj: O,
  keys: Array<K> | Set<K>,
): R => {
  const keysSet = keys instanceof Array ? new Set(keys) : keys;
  // ✅ kinda LIE by casting to string keys union
  const originalKeys = Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof O>;

  return originalKeys.reduce(
    (acc, keyName) => {      
      if(!keysSet.has(keyName as K)){
        // ✅ NO ERROR
        acc[keyName] = obj[keyName]
      }

      return acc
    },
    // ✅ LIE TO ACCUMULATOR! OUCH!
    {} as O,
  // ✅ CAST WHOLE REDUCE result to demanded outcome
  ) as R;
};
```

So question is if there is some better solution as this one feels quite hacky/verbose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when dealing with generics you will end up with some type assertions here and there in the implementation. I think when writing generic functions the focus should generally be on call site type safety, while trying to minimize type assertions in the implementation.

The version I have would remove the `R` parameter as that should always be `Omit<O, K>` and the extra type parameter will prevent assignment of `O` to the result (Since `R` could theoretically have extra props).

Second, the assignment `acc[keyName] = obj[keyName]`  will only succeed if both sides of the assignment would be `O[keyof O]` (or at least the same exact type, since we are dealing with generics). The simplest way to do that would be to  start from `{} as O` in reduce.

Fortunately ts will figure out that `O` is assignable to `Omit<O, K>` so no more type assertions there.

Opinions may vary as to where you do the asserting, but that is the least amount of assertions I can come up with. Hope this helps, good luck with it

```
export const omitProps = <
  O extends Record<string,any>, 
  K extends keyof O
>(
  obj: O,
  keys: Array<K> | Set<K>,
): Omit<O, K> => {
  const keysSet: Set<K | keyof O> = keys instanceof Array ? new Set(keys) : keys;
  const originalKeys = Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof O>;

  return originalKeys.reduce(
    (acc, keyName) => {      
      if(!keysSet.has(keyName)){
        acc[keyName] = obj[keyName]
      }

      return acc
    },
    {} as O,
  );
};
```